# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]; Python Packages

Tags: python, file-not-found

I am working on a project that includes disabling usb ports in python, I am trying to test out some code I found that should work but I am getting a FileNotFound error.

```
import subprocess

# Fetches the list of all usb devices:
result = subprocess.run(['devcon', 'hwids', '=usb'],
                        capture_output=True, text=True)

# ... add code to parse the result and get the hwid of the device you want ...


subprocess.run(['devcon', 'disable', 'ACPI\VEN_HPQ&DEV_8002'])  # to enable
```

I have no idea why this is erroring because of my limited python knowledge but any help would be appreciated.
error message :
line 548, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

line 1024, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds

I have tried downloading different packages that other stack overflow users said on other threads and none of it worked.

Comment: Have you installed the [required packages for devcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon)? You normally have to install a WDK or similar for it to be available.

Comment: yes, I am using WDK and VSCode comes with Devcon